# Why does `wrapfigure` leave so much vertical space?

Tags: wrapfigure

[image]

```latex
\subsection{Intrinsic Rewards}
Most exploration approaches struggle, when the rewards for actions have long delays (i.e. when rewards are sparse). Recall our room navigation example again, and imagine a second goal \(\tilde{G}\) closer to the start with a smaller reward. Then the algorithm will most likely stumble into the secondary goal first and the action values around this secondary goal will relatively quickly be updated to lead towards this goal. 

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                    \draw (\x,\y) rectangle +(1,1);
                }
            }
            \node at (0.5,1.5){\(\tilde{G}\)};
            \node at (1.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (1.5,2.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (2.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (3.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (2.5,0.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (3.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (0.5,2.5){\(\downarrow\)};
            \node at (1.5,3.5){\(\downarrow\)};
            \node at (2.5,2.5){\(\downarrow\)};
            \node at (0.5,0.5){\(\uparrow\)};
            \node at (1.5,0.5){S};
            \node at (3.5, 4.5){G};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

In case of the \(\vep\)-greedy policy, the occasional exploratory actions will only cause a one step deviation from the shortest path to this secondary goal, and the algorithm will use its knowledge about the surroundings to quickly walk back towards this goal using subsequent greedy actions. While finding the larger goal, requires multiple subsequent exploratory actions, leading away from the secondary goal.
```

Comment: Certainly, the `center` environment contributes to the space...try `\centering` instead.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks that helped a bit

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document .

Comment: No one can run your example to trace the spacing decisions so it's really impossible to help (it would also help tracing if you could replace the tikz with something simpler, say `\rule{2cm}{2cm}`  so long as you can show the same spacing issue.

Comment: Also, wrapfig ignores the effects for \parskip.  The \intextsep gap is deliberate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapfig is easily confused by the environment it finds itself placed in and tends to be somewhat conservative in spacing. So If I restructure your request to a more conventional one this is the result.

[image]

Further to comment by Leandriis I have dropped the top mater and thus increased the whitespace yet still kept the "cut lines" at [15] that could be reduced to [14] if there is no need for a caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig,tikz}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Intrinsic Rewards}
Most exploration approaches struggle, when the rewards for actions have long delays (i.e. when rewards are sparse). Recall our room navigation example again, and imagine a second goal \(\tilde{G}\) closer to the start with a smaller reward. Then the algorithm will most likely stumble into the secondary goal first and the action values around this secondary goal will relatively quickly be updated.
\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{r}{5.5cm}\centering% Title (Topmatter)
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}{
                    \draw (\x,\y) rectangle +(1,1);
                }
            }
            \node at (0.5,1.5){\(\tilde{G}\)};
            \node at (1.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (1.5,2.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (2.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (3.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (2.5,0.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (3.5,1.5){\(\leftarrow\)};
            \node at (0.5,2.5){\(\downarrow\)};
            \node at (1.5,3.5){\(\downarrow\)};
            \node at (2.5,2.5){\(\downarrow\)};
            \node at (0.5,0.5){\(\uparrow\)};
            \node at (1.5,0.5){S};
            \node at (3.5, 4.5){G};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \small\textbf{Wrapfig[15] (Room for caption)}
    \end{wrapfigure}

In case of the greedy policy, the occasional exploratory actions will only cause a one step deviation from the shortest path to this secondary goal, and the algorithm will use its knowledge about the surroundings to quickly walk back towards this goal using subsequent greedy actions. While finding the larger goal, requires multiple subsequent exploratory actions, leading away from the secondary goal. \lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `\begin{wrapfigure}[16]` to allow for a bit of vertical white space between the caption and the last line(s)  of text.

Comment: Is there a way to force the number of lines to be "the perfect size" ? Or do we always have to do it manually ?